# How to increment DateTime field in SQL Server 2005 by a month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, datetime

I have a DateTime field in SQL Server for some products expiration (ExpirationDate). I need to increment all the items manually, and set their expiration a month later than the date stored in the field currently. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have SQL Server on my computer, so I cannot test, but what about using [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258267%28SQL.80%29.aspx), a bit like this :

```
update your_table set your_field = DATEADD(month, 1, your_field)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean to say update your_table, fixed it for you.

Answer (score 9):

```
UPDATE Products SET ExpirationDate=DATEADD(month,1,ExpirationDate) WHERE Type='Cheese'
```

Comment: Exactly, it only gets cheesier.